# PHP : How To Get Strings Between 2 Static Strings?

Tags: php

I have this case :

```
<!-- [STATIC STRING] -->
Some HTML codes here
<!-- [STATIC STRING END] -->
```

How to get that any codes between STATIC STRING and STATIC STRING END in PHP? Is it possible to get something in between same condition like this :

```
<!-- [STATIC STRING] -->
Some HTML codes here
<!-- [STATIC STRING] -->
```

I just need to put some string between something so later on I can manipulate it using PHP. Any idea how to make it efficient?

**UPDATE** : let's say that HTML code stored as file.html and on the other side I have this PHP script :

```
$Filename = 'file.html';
$Handle = fopen($Filename, "r");
$Contents = fread($Handle, filesize($Filename));
fclose($Handle);
```

from this PHP, I have no clue how to get HTML code between `<!-- [STATIC STRING] -->` and `<!-- [STATIC STRING END] -->`. and to make it simpler... just assume that there are no other codes before and after it. what I need is the code between those two and put it as PHP variable.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what is this for actually? Are you parsing some XML files?

Comment: please check my update. I have add more detail information.

Comment: Just to understand the question: Is there any need to parse the file? As long as you have control over the file.html: Why not just change it to file.phtml and use <?php echo $someHTMLContent ?> instead of <!-- [STATIC STRING] -->Some HTML codes here<!-- [STATIC STRING] --> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to extract data from a string

```
function extractor($str,$from,$to)
{
    $from_pos = strpos($str,$from);
    $from_pos = $from_pos + strlen($from);
    $to_pos   = strpos($str,$to,$from_pos);// to must be after from
    $return   = substr($str,$from_pos,$to_pos-$from_pos);
    unset($str,$from,$to,$from_pos,$to_pos );           
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: In my case, $str will be $Contents, $from = <!-- [STATIC STRING] --> and $to = <!-- [STATIC STRING END] -->, is that what you mean?

Comment: yes it will work for it. It will extract data between from and to

Comment: I have no doubt... your solution is the shortest and smartest solution. accepted as answer. thanks bro!

Comment: Is there a need to `unset` all those local variables?

Comment: No, it is not necessary to use unset here. All variables, that are allocated inside a function will become free when you leave the function. For further information about this, look here http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/18/1/10

Comment: is there more then one tag in the file, id prefer preg_match_all see my answer, 1 line of code.

Answer (score 1):

try regx

```
staticstring(.*)staticstring
```

Comment: could you please check my update and see if works with RegEx? thanks.

Comment: When you work with static strings and larger input, you should consider using strpos rather than regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of to what you want is a heredoc:

```
public $myHTML = <<<EOT
<div>bar</div>
EOT;
```

If you just want something embeded in your html for later use by for example a screen scraper etc then why not just embed the html you want in a div with an id that you can reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to PHP, you will need to check [strlen](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strlen.asp), [strpos](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strpos.asp) and [substr](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp) functions for PHP
sample code:

```
<?php
    $str = "[STATIC STRING]
        Some HTML codes here
        [STATIC STRING END]";
    $answer = $str;
    $start_text = "[STATIC STRING]";
    $end_text = "[STATIC STRING END]";
    $start_index = strpos($answer,$start_text)+strlen($start_text);
    $answer = substr($answer,$start_index);

    $end_index = strpos($answer,$end_text);
    $answer = substr($answer,0,$end_index);

    echo $answer;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this as it works for more then one tag in the file, ( won't cover nested tags )

```
preg_match_all('<!--\s\[STATIC\sSTRING\]\s-->(?P<match>(?:(?!<!--\s\[STATIC\sSTRING\sEND\]\s-->).)*)<!--\s\[STATIC\sSTRING\sEND\]\s-->', $string, $match);
```

Then $match['match'] will have your data.

Took me a few minutes on this one,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <!-- [STATIC STRING] -->
Some HTML codes here
<!-- [STATIC STRING END] -->
        )

    [match] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
Some HTML codes here

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
Some HTML codes here

        )

)
```

ps. you should be able to

```
$arr = array_map('trim', $match['match']);
```

and remove all the outside space.

personally id go with a tag like this,

```
<!-- { html content } -->
```

be much easier to match.

```
$string = '<!-- { STATIC STRING } -->
<b> hello</b>
<!-- { <strong>Other STATIC STRING</strong> } -->';

preg_match_all('/<!--\s\{(?P<match>(?:(?!\}\s-->).)*)\}\s-->/', $string, $match);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <!-- { STATIC STRING } -->
            [1] => <!-- { <strong>Other STATIC STRING</strong> } -->
        )

    [match] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  STATIC STRING 
            [1] =>  <strong>Other STATIC STRING</strong> 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  STATIC STRING 
            [1] =>  <strong>Other STATIC STRING</strong> 
        )

)
```